# It's possible to update a record?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following Record:

```
 ({
  ServiceModel service,
  int count,
 });



 final test =  (service: ServiceModel(), count: 1)
```

I want to update the count of my record (for example from 1 to N). It's possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to mutate a `Record`. [`Record`s are immutable](https://dart.dev/language/records).

You instead will need to create a new record with the updated value or will need to create a class.